# Parse push notifcations open source server

Tags: android, node.js, parse-platform, push-notification

Parse is shutting down and they've made their server opensource. However they do not have the extended functionality with push notifications as what used to be the case with parse.com

Can anyone help me set up push notifications on the open source version of Parse on android?
I've been through their wiki and I'm a tad bit confused about it.

If I'm not wrong, should I just add the GCM credentials to where the Parse Server is being initialized and then deploy it manually (possibly to heroku) myself and then use cURL to send notifications as per the wiki?
Or did I misunderstand the whole process and need to do something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host your own Parser Server in a self-hosting solution or use a Parse Hosting provider like https://www.back4app.com

See all options below:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#parse-server-sample-application

Then you can send the push notifications using dashboard console, API or cloud code. Note that push notifications cannot be sent anymore from client. Because of security issues, Parse Server has discontinued sending push notifications direct from client. The best practice now is to create a cloud function to send the push notifications and then call it from client code. See more details below:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push#4-send-push-notifications

And here there is an example of a cloud function that can be used to send push notifications:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('push', function (request, response) {
    // THIS METHOD NO LONGER WORKS
    // Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    Parse.Push.send({
        channels: request.params.channels,
        data: request.params.data
    }, {
        // ADD THE `useMasterKey` TO THE OPTIONS OBJECT
        useMasterKey: true,
        success: function () {
            response.success('Success!');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error('Error! ' + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

You can also send the push notification throw Parse Dashboard. Parse has just announced this feature is now available:
http://blog.parse.com/announcements/push-and-config-come-to-the-parse-dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

just fill the GCM field and the second field when you initialize Parse server (in the index.js or the ecosystem.json)... this will allow the server to send the Push for Android, for sending push U can use cloud code, curl or whatever. You need to use **MasterKey** though

Comment: But this means I have to deploy it myself rather than use the deploy to heroku button provided in the parse server example yeah?

Also, where does one write cloud code?

Comment: I am using VPS and set everything by myself, search info on github, if you got some problem search issues there, everything what you are asking has been resolved! [https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)